# Validity of reflection positivity in lattice models and field theories

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

Reflection positivity concerns the semi-positive definite nature of expectation values of the type $\langle F\theta_{P}F \rangle \ge 0$. Here, $\theta_{P}$ denotes reflection with respect to the plane $P$. In the above, $F$ is a general function of fields (or spins, etc.) and $\theta_{P}$ is a  reflection operator defined by $\theta_{P} F(x) = F(\theta_{P} x)$. That is, $\theta_{P}$ transforms the argument(s) of F to the reflection or mirror image(s) (in the plane $P$) of the coordinate(s) $x$ on which it is defined. The average $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is computed with a measure that is (up to a normalization factor) given by $e^{-H}$ with $H$ a Hamiltonian (or action) that is reflection invariant: $\theta_{P} H = H$.

My naive question is how general is this inequality of $\langle F \theta_{P} F \rangle \ge 0$? Does $F$ need to have its support only on local spatial regions $x$? In simple lattice proofs, I can see how this can be demonstrated by having the plane $P$ lie along a line of sites, etc., with local $F$ and Hamiltonians $H$ that are sums of local terms. Does this trivially hold or fail for a many body system with long range interactions? For which quantum system does it hold?

The literature seems focused on imaginary time questions and spin systems.

Comment: It would be nice to have more precise definitions in the question. Anyhow, $F$ needs to be supported on a half-space. If you are new to this, a good intro is the review by Biskup https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0610025 section 5. Also the book https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/ Chapter 10. Finally, your model does not need to only have short range interactions like nearest neighbor Ising. Long-range models are also reflection positive for suitable exponents.

Comment: Indeed, I was not being very precise and specific in the question since I wished to know the general circumstances under which the Reflection Positivity inequality holds. Thank you very much for the comment! These references also look very useful.

Comment: If you need more info on the long-range case, see the proof of Theorem 7.1 in the article by Gubinelli and Hofmanova https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01700